# Determine if product key is used on multiple computers

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, license, product-key

I'm the sole programmer at company. Not only that, I'm the sole person who's remotely computer literate above the "I can check my email". As such, I've been asked to go to all the machines, and determine if any of the computers have duplicate install keys (the theory is the guy before me just didn't care and randomly used whatever key he pulled). Is there a way to determine this without installing any additional software?

Comment: How were they deployed? Via imaging or using install discs? If discs, where are they? If not, are you sure it wasn't a volume license? Do you have any credentials for https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx ? Check any and all contracts or software documentation you have.

Comment: I will throw [a link in](http://learn-powershell.net/2012/05/04/updating-an-existing-get-productkey-function/) and wait for your response if this is worth a long answer :D. The basic idea is to use Powershell to query Windows keys even from remote machines, get it into an Excel sheet and use a function to search duplicates

Comment: @Raystafarian: They were done using install discs. I have all the discs, and keys, just no notion of where they go, as I wasn't the one who installed it, and the other guy didn't keep track.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, as long as you have enough keys for all the machines, as outlined by the EULA, it doesn't matter if you get audited because you haven't exceeded your allowance. If someone gets an error on a key, you can call MS to find out what the problem is and get the key reset or put another one on. Adobe is a different story. I say this not because this isn't a valid question, but because you may want to save some hassle.

Comment: @Raystafarian: So, even if he used the same key on all the computers, so long as I have actual keys to go around, we're okay?

Comment: @CL4PTR4P I'm assuming we're talking about Windows license keys, and not simply a 3rd party product installed on Windows?

Comment: @CL4PTR4P If you're talking about Windows licenses, then yes, you should be OK. You paid to license Windows for X number of computers, and as long as you're not trying to run Windows on more than X computers, you're good.

Comment: @DarthAndroid: Correct.

Comment: Depending on how many computers you manage, it may be worth looking at getting a Volume License Agreement so that you don't have to worry about tracking individual keys and licenses. Last time I checked, you could get a VLK for as few as 5 computers.

Comment: @nixda. I've tried running that script, but it doesn't output anything

Comment: Agreed, VLK is much easier to manage, even if a machine fails, you can call and explain that you can't recover the key and they'll add usages on. Plus you build a relationship with MS. Sometimes you can get into programs where you get free stuff by having the VLK

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Please see my updated answer and report your experiences with the new script

Answer (score 1):

Try and download Nirsoft's Produkey software.  Install on USB key.  Walk around, run it and send output to a file on the key.  Doesn't require full installation - runs standalone.  Shows OS key and Office key.  May show other keys as well.

Answer (score 1):

With Nirsoft's Produkey, you can retrieve all keys from computers on the network if you have local administrator rights on each or domain administrator rights with the command line flags /remoteall or /remotealldomain domain.com

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

The idea is to use PowerShell to query the [license keys of list of PC names](http://learn-powershell.net/2012/05/04/updating-an-existing-get-productkey-function/) (input.csv).

The script will also check for duplicate keys and write the PC-Name, its corresponding license key and the duplicate check result to a new CSV (output.csv).

#### How to use

1. Create a CSV list as input. Write just one PC name per line. Save it as *Input.csv*
   In my example I query my own PC four times.
   [image]
2. Download two PowerShell scripts to the same location as your input CSV

   `Get-ProductKey.ps1` contains a single function to get product keys of local and remote systems and can be downloaded from [Microsoft's script center.](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-product-keys-of-local-83b4ce97)

   `Write-ProductKeyList.ps1` will use the input CSV and the function script to write a new output CSV containing the results. Download it from [Github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3cbe2a48f7b1e1af4733) or use the code below.

   ```
   . .\Get-ProductKey.ps1
   $InputCSV = import-csv .\Input.csv -Header Name
   $OutputCSV = @()  
   $Keys =@()

   foreach ($PC in $InputCSV)  
   {   
       $objResult = Get-ProductKey -Computername $PC.name                    
       $checkResult = $Keys -contains $objResult.ProductKey      
       $Keys += $objResult.ProductKey             
       $objResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Duplicate -value $checkResult          
       $OutputCSV = $OutputCSV + $objResult        
   }         
   $OutputCSV | Select-object Computername,OSDescription,ProductKey,Duplicate | export-csv -path .\Output.csv -noType
   ```
3. If you have all three files with the exact names at the same location, you're ready to go.
   Run the `Write-ProductKeyList.ps1` script via right-click and *Run with Powershell*

**Result** (output.csv)

You will get a CSV file at the same location which you can open with Excel. The first occurrence of any license key will be marked with *False*, meaning there is yet no duplicate. Of course, all further (duplicate) keys will be marked as *True* meaning "Yes, this key was already used somewhere"
 [image]

#### Preliminaries

- remote Windows machines must be reachable via network (obviously)
- "Remote Registry" service must be running on every remote machine (by default its on)